# How to move checkbox & label inside dive to the right of the card

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to move a div containing a checkbox and label inside of a card to the right of the card.

As of now it only is staying on the left. I have tried "float:right" many times with and without position as absolute and I only manage to move the label and not the checkbox to the right. I am using bootstrap and have tried to add text-right in the class and as expected it only moved the label.

How can I move both the label and checkbox inside the div to the right of the card?

```
<div style="position:absolute;"class="text-right boxes">
    <input type="checkbox" id="box-2">
    <label for="box-2">On/Off</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
label,input{
float:right;
margin-top:10%;}

div{
width:80%;}
```

```html
<div  style="position:absolute;"class="text-right boxes">
<label for="box-2">On/Off</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="box-2">
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of way to position elements. I prefer `flexbox`.

```css
.boxes {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: 250px;
  border: dashed black 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
    <input type="checkbox" id="box-2">
    <label for="box-2">On/Off</label>
</div>
```

If you use `bootstrap` you can choose following.

```css
.boxes {
  width: 250px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: dashed black 1px;
}

.boxes label {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="boxes text-right">
  <input type="checkbox" id="box-2">
  <label for="box-2">On/Off</label>
</div>

<div class="boxes d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center">
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="box-2">
    <label for="box-2">On/Off</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="boxes">
  <div class="float-right">
    <input type="checkbox" id="box-2">
    <label for="box-2">On/Off</label>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div><!--NB! You have <clear: value> after using float!-->
</div>
```